# Setting the row style of a ComponentOne DataTree FlexGrid

Tags: c#, styles, componentone, c1flexgrid

I am using a ComponentOne DataTree that is a FlexGrid with child grids.  The parent grid has 2 columns a 'Select' column which is a checkbox and another column that is read-only.  The child grid has 5 columns.  The first is a checkbox and the other 4 are readonly.  The read-only columns appear gray by default.  I set the DataTable columns that is the data source of the grids to ReadOnly.  I want the non-header columns to have a background of white by default.  Neither grid is updated.

I define the style as a member variable and create the style in the Initialize method:

```
C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.CellStyle defaultRowStyle;
 private void InitializeControls()
    {
        txtWorkZone.Enabled = true;
        txtWorkZone.Focus();

        defaultRowStyle = c1flxdatatreeCasePick.Styles.Add("DefaultRowStyle");
        defaultRowStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
```

This is the OwnerDrawCell method that sets it:

```
 private void c1flxdatatreeCasePick_OwnerDrawCell(object sender, OwnerDrawCellEventArgs e)
    {
        C1FlexDataTree grid = sender as C1FlexDataTree;
        if (grid == null || grid.DataSource == null)
            return;

        if(e.Row > 0)
            grid.Rows[e.Row].Style = grid.Styles["DefaultRowStyle"];

        //Get the child grid
        C1FlexDataTree childGrid = grid.Rows[e.Row].UserData as C1FlexDataTree;

        if (childGrid != null)
        {
            if(e.Row > 0)
                 childGrid.Rows[e.Row].Style = grid.Styles["DefaultRowStyle"];                 
        }
    }
```

Why won't the grids get the row style setting?

Thanks
Gloria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont be able to use OwnerDrawCell as you've expected here. After the FlexGrid is loaded on the form use the following snippet used to repaint readonly columns background:

```
C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.CellStyle cs;
cs = _flex.Cols[2].StyleDisplay;
cs.BackColor = Color.White;
cs = _flex.Cols[3].StyleDisplay;
cs.BackColor = Color.White;
```

If you need to change the background color of the Child Tables you have to change each child's properties individually. Use the following snippet to access the Child tables:

```
for (int row = 0; row <  _flex.Rows.Count; row++)
{
C1FlexDataTree child = _flex.Rows[row].UserData as C1FlexDataTree;
if (child != null)
{
      // Access Child Tables here 
}
}
```

To make the child tables in my C1FlexDataTree read-only:

```
for (int row = 0; row <  _flex.Rows.Count; row++)
{
C1FlexDataTree child = _flex.Rows[row].UserData as C1FlexDataTree;
if (child != null)
{
    foreach (Column c in child.Cols)
    {
        c.AllowEditing = false;
    }
}
}
```